# Find div and submit button in datalist

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to post when user clicks on a div within a datalist, my jQuery is supposed to find my hidden button (display:none) and then post. I'm not able to fetch the click event.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebUserControl1.ascx.cs"
    Inherits="Everything.controls.WebUserControl1" %>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert("I'm seeing this alert");
        $(".divcontainer").click(function () {

            $(this).find("input").click();
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="myForm" style="padding-bottom: 0; padding-top: 50px; margin-bottom: 0.3em">
    <asp:DataList ID="lstCategoryItems" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div id="myDivId" class="divcontainer cf" runat="server">
                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Key") %>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="BtnClick" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Value") %>'
                    Style="display: none" />
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can find the input this way:

```
   $(".divcontainer input:hidden").click(function(){
      ....
   })
```

or if you have an another handler for input:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("I'm seeing this alert");
    $(".divcontainer").click(function () {
        $(this).find("input:hidden").trigger("click");
    });

    $("input").click(function(){

    })
});
```

Comment: Solved it, had another problem the usercontrol resides in an updatepanel which generated som problems, had to fetch it through parent element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cE8X6/3/)

```
$(".divcontainer").click(function () {
    $('#mybtn').trigger('click');
});
```